# Filter data from 2 lists with diferent models C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this models

```
public class RoutingAttributeModel
{
    public int Bus_No { get; set; }
    public int Attribute_No { get; set; }
    public string Attribute_Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}

public class AgentRoutingAttributeModel
{
    public int Agent_No { get; set; }
    public int Bus_No { get; set; }
    public int Attribute_No { get; set; }
    public string Attribute_Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

List<RoutingAttributeModel> lstComplete = new List<RoutingAttributeModel>();
List<AgentRoutingAttributeModel> lstAssigned = new List<AgentRoutingAttributeModel>();
```

Filled this with some data

Is it possible to filter with Linq? I want to save in a new list the diferent content between lstComplete and lstAssigned

I was trying to join both lists but got stuck there

```
var results1 = from cl in lstComplete 
                       join al in lstAssigned 
                       on cl.Attribute_No equals al.Attribute_No
                       select cl;
```

Comment: I don't know if C# has sumtypes so you can define a type which is either your first or second model, or maybe you can define an interface that both models can satisfy in order to do what you want. In theory that would allow you to have a list of that interface/union on which you would be able to filter with the interface's common fields.

Comment: By different do you mean variables that are not in either?

Comment: Exactly I want to save the content that is not assigned, I updated my question I was trying to join the lists with Linq but got stuck there

Comment: Your talking in your own lingo. What is "not assigned"? Yeah, probably something like  items in `lstComplete` that are not in `lstAssigned`. But what defines "not in"? I'm pretty sure that if you try to put that in formal language you also know how to query it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq
as my understanding, you try to find linked by attribute_No records and have a list of not matching properties?

```
lstComplete.Add(new RoutingAttributeModel(){
    Attribute_Name = "aaa",
    Attribute_No = 1,
    Bus_No = 1,
    Notes = "",
    Status = "status"
    });
    

    lstAssigned.Add(new AgentRoutingAttributeModel()
    {
    Attribute_No = 1,
    Agent_No = 10,
    Bus_No = 1,
    Attribute_Name = "bbb",
    Status = "status2"
    });

    var lst = lstComplete
       .Join(lstAssigned,
           complete => complete.Attribute_No,
           assigned => assigned.Attribute_No,
           (complete, assigned) => new { lstComplete = complete, lstAssigned = assigned })
               .Select(s => new { s.lstComplete, s.lstAssigned})
               .Where(w=> 
                    w.lstAssigned.Attribute_Name != w.lstComplete.Attribute_Name
                    || w.lstAssigned.Bus_No != w.lstComplete.Bus_No
               )
               .ToList()
               .Dump();
```

so result would be
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following query

```
var filteredList = lstComplete
               .Where(x => !lstAssigned.Any(y => y.Attribute_No == x.Attribute_No));
```